# How to deploy adapter to local MFP server with CLI?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

I have been looking for MFP CLI doc how to deploy adapter to local MFP server but can't find one. I also can't find one in `mfp help adapter`.

What is the command?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `mfp push` to push an adapter to your locally running MobileFirst Server.